# Unexpected array behavior

Tags: ruby, arrays, variables

The following **modify** method somehow modifies the whole **@x** array instead of just simply generating another element to be pushed later. How come?

```
def modify i, s
  t = @x[-1]
  t[i] = t[i] + s
  t
end

@x = [ [10, 12] ]
@x << modify(0, 1)

puts @x
```

**Edited**
The following code have done the trick. Still I wonder if its possible to get rid of the p-argument

```
def modify p, i, s
  a = p.to_a
  a[i] += s*@delta[i]
  Vector.elements( a )
end
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish here. What do you want the method to do? Also, why are you referring to a specific instance variable (`@x`) in the method, rather than, say, `self`?

Comment: it is clear exactly why this method modifies the whole @x. unclear is what you are trying to accomplish. what is the application of this? can you elaborate on the context?

Comment: I'm trying to modify a shared vector (@x[-1]) and then push modified version to the @x array.

Comment: The problem consists of two parts:
1. I need to modify only a single component of a vector
2. Vector can hold float components (.clone won't do the trick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@x[-1]` is the inner array [10, 12]. You set `t` to reference this array. You then modify this array with the `t[i] =` part.

Comment: how do I set t-variable not to reference, but to only pick the value?

Comment: lose the t[i]= and replace it with any new variable

Comment: @avguchenko: As I said in the comments to your answer, that wouldn't have the desired effect. He appears to want a modified version of the array. Replacing the mutation of `t` with a variable holding a single element of `t` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably redo from start, but in the spirit of small changes ... try changing your method to reduce side effects.

If you want to return a single Fixnum element:

```
def modify i, s
  t = @x[-1]
  r = t[i] + s
  r
end
```

or, if you want to return an array to inject into the greater array of tuples

```
def modify i, s
  t = @x[-1].dup
  t[i] = t[i] + s
  t
end
```

In the spirit of understanding, you should read up on Ruby objects and how they are references and how Ruby methods have has side-effects.

Study this:

```
a=[1,2]
b=a
b[0]=4
puts a
> [4,2]
```

You might want to do a dupe

```
a=[1,2]
b=a.dup
b[0]=4
puts a
> [1,2]
```

Comment: too many sub-variables... is there a chance to pass the value, not the *link* ?

Comment: This not only removes the side-effect, it also changes the return type of the method. Previously, it returned an array. This version returns an integer. Since it appears to be an array of arrays, this is probably incorrect.

Comment: I think we can all agree that there are numerous problems with gmile's example.

Comment: @Chuck: the question specified that he wanted to generate "another element to be pushed later." I think this is a side effect of the vagueness of the question.  I do not feel the downvote is fair.